# How to implement an avl tree in c++ with each node being another avl tree

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I Have an input.txt file which contains number like this:[input.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZADac.png)

I am trying to make an avl tree in which every node is a number form the first column and each of these nodes point to another avl tree containing numbers from the second column.Could someone explain how to implement this in c++?

Comment: This question is not good for stackoverflow. Read something about the topic and start coding and once you are stuck, people will be happy to help you with a specific problem. "How to implement" not only tend to be very broad questions (which are not good questions for SO), they also lack showable effort (Something which SO requires from the user).

Comment: I'm confused.  I thought in a binary or AVL tree, each node can be another AVL (subtree) or a leaf node.  So how is your implementation different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement this as you would with an integer node:

```
struct AVL_node
{
  bool color;
  int key;
  AVL_Tree value;
  AVL_Node * left_subtree;
  AVL_Node * right_subtree;
};
```

In a tree, you need to separate the key, value and link fields.  The key is what you are using for ordering the nodes.  The value is the data.

The value doesn't make a difference.  It could be `std::vector` or `std::map` or missing.  Nodes in general are not copied, only the links change.  However, if a node is copied, both the key and value fields are copied.

Remembering, when organizing nodes, only the link fields change.  The key is used to determine ordering.